# Geth Node Connection

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, ubuntu

I connecting to my GethNode of Private Block chain setup with Ubuntu. But whenever i exit from terminal my GethConnection also get terminated and mining also stops.
How to keep alive the Geth Connection and Mining after disconnecting from the terminal.

Thanks
AKM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tmux` to continue your process even after disconnecting your terminal. Typing `tmux` in your console starts it. `tmux ls` will list down all available terminals. And you can connect back with `tmux attach -t 0` to connect to terminal 0 listed from `tmux ls`.